# Create button dynamically and assign a function to it

Tags: javascript, function, button, assign

I am populating a table with a function using JS, and want a button I'm creating as part of the table to call a function when it's clicked. Every time I try to assign a function to the button, the function gets called during creation and then the button does not work once the table is populated. I have tried:

```
button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
buttonText = document.createTextNode("Edit");
button.setAttribute("name",name);
button.appendChild(buttonText);
button.type = "button";
button.onclick = new function(){alert('clicked');};
```

And I've tried:

```
button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
buttonText = document.createTextNode("Edit");
button.setAttribute("name",name);
button.appendChild(buttonText);
button.type = "button";
button.setAttribute('onclick', new function(){alert('clicked');};
```

Neither one allow this function to be executed when the button is clicked after the table has been created. (But does execute while the button is being created.) I'm sure this is relatively straight-forward, but how do I assign a function to the onclick event of the button in my table? Most everything I have found in the documentation, and on these forums says to use the methods above. All help is much appreciated!

Comment: You don't need the `new` construct - just assign a function.

Comment: I figured out the problem...I was trying to assign the function BEFORE the table was attached to the DOM. Simple. Note for anyone having this problem...be sure the elements exist in the DOM before assigning click event functions! :) Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

try to change

```
button.onclick = new function(){alert('clicked');};
```

into

```
button.onclick = function(){alert('clicked');};
```